# Two Java dice rolling programs. How do I get these two programs to run properly? How can I condense this? (new to Java)

Tags: java, object, constructor

So the first program is a basic object which is a die.  It has six sides and basically prints the face-up value of what is rolled.  How can I declare this method correctly? It also can not resolve some of the values I have, and I don't know what that means in all honesty.

Here is the code.

```
public class Die {

    private int numSides;
    private int value;


    public die(int numSidesInput) {
        numSides = numSidesInput;
        myDie = numSides;
        roll();


    public void roll(int die) {
        numSides = 6;
        this.value = (int) (Math.random() * numSides) + 1;
    }


    public int getValue() {
        return getValue = value;
    }

}
```

---

The second program is a game with two dice objects.  The dice have 20 sides, and the die with the highest roll wins.  If they are the same then it ends in a tie.  I'm a little lost on this one and am confused on a lot of it.  Am I on the right track? Any tips would be helpful!  Here is the code for the game...

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        private int die1;
        private int die2;

        public PairOfDice() {
            roll();
        }

    public void roll() {
        die1 = (int)(Math.random()*20) + 1;
        die2 = (int)(Math.random()*20) + 1;
    }

    if (die1 > die2) {
        system.out.println ("Player 1 won")
    }
    else if (die2 > die1) {
        system.out.println ("Player 2 won")
    }
    else if (die1==die2) {
        system.out.println ("TIE")
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return getValue = value;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: There is no variable called `myDie` declared anywhere.

Comment: Why are you taking `numSidesInput` as a parameter when ultimately you will set it to `6`?

Comment: @ambigram_maker do I just change that to 'die'?

Comment: There are multiple basic issues here that indicate that you don't know how to initialise variables, declare constructors, and other basics of Java. I suggest starting from the beginning of a Java book and getting the basics down, before taking on this dice problem.

Comment: I totally agree with @slim. Go to the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), download them if you please, fix the problems you can and then post on SO. _Good Luck!_ :-)

Comment: @ambigram_maker Thanks for the link.  And obviously this is a little over my current ability with Java, but I'd rather learn it now since I'm here!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your existing class 'Die':

1. Constructor is case-sensitive & must match the name of the class. `public Die (int numSidesInput)` rather than 'die'.
2. `roll()` taking a parameter conflicts with the class, the class already has a field `numberOfSides`.
3. `getValue()` syntax is incorrect. It should just be `return value;`.

But there are some design questions here, as to what would really be a useful/ preferable design for actually *using* the die/ or dice. Usage & doing things are the fundamental tasks by which design must be measured.

Design-wise, a couple of points:

1. There's not much usefulness in separating `roll()` and `getValue()`. Ideal design would probably just make `roll()` return the result. Unless you want to look at the die's value more than once, there's no real need to keep the value in it's state.
2. There's a question as to whether embodying the "number of sides" in a Die instance is actually useful, or whether it would be simpler to just pass "number of sides" as a parameter.

With regard to the second, the difference in usage would look like:

```
Die d20 = new Die(20);
int playerRoll = d20.roll();
int monsterRoll = d20.roll();
```

versus:

```
// just a static method now, we've eliminated all state
int playerRoll = Die.roll(20);
int monsterRoll = Die.roll(20);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  So just get rid of the parameter in the roll class?

Comment: `public int getValue() {return value;}`

Comment: So to return the value in the roll class, would I just 'return value;' ?

Comment: Exactly. Actually, I don't think this is a bad way to learn.. dice/ or using them appear to be quite a good example.

Comment: Also, with the second part.  I would just put those under PairOfDice?

Comment: Pairing or grouping a number of dice, is only where they are all adding to the same result.  Rolling one die against another, is not that.

Comment: A one-on-one tutorial is a good way to learn, but SO is not the place for it. Maybe move to chat?

Comment: I feel like my PairOfDice class is useless... is it?  And in regards to the second one, would I get rid of 'private int die1' as well as the second and just replace it with the style you showed me?  And I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: You haven't got a PairOfDice class. There isn't one declared. Again, go through a Java book from the beginning, doing the exercises, not moving on until you've understood each part. There's strong evidence here that you're just typing in stuff that looks a bit like Java without understanding what it means.

Comment: @slim I understand where you're coming from.  I will read up a lot more on it, but I set out to at least finish this! It's a learning experience.